# Hide records from datatables based on database value 0/1

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to hide the records fetched from my database based on their value if its 0 or 1, its displaying all records i just want to display the ones with value 1, I'm using Laravel 5.2 with Yajra/Datatables.

this is my controller:

```
public function get() {
    if(!access()->allow('customers.read')) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->withFlashDanger(trans('customers.general.messages.denied'));
    } else {
        $customers = Customer::select(array(
            'id', 'code', 'name', 'rnc', 'ced', 'phone', 'email', 'active'
        ));

        return Datatables::of($customers->get('status'), $customers->get('trashed'))
            ->addColumn('actions', function($customers) {
                return $customers->action_buttons;

            })->addColumn('check', '<input type="checkbox" name="selected_users[]" value="{{ $id }}">')
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.master')

@section('title', app_name() . ' | ' . trans('customers.general.customers_title'))

@section('after-styles-end')
{{ Html::style("css/backend/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css") }}
@stop

@section('page-header')
    <h1>
        {{ trans('customers.general.customers_title') }} <small>- {{ trans('customers.general.general') }}</small>
    </h1>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="box box-success">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">{{ trans('customers.general.customers_list') }}</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <a href="{{ route('admin.customers.create') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{ trans('customers.general.buttons.new_customer') }}</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
    <!-- Begins Customers Page  -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="customers-table" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
                    <th class="">{{ trans('customers.general.table.code') }}</th>
                    <th class="">{{ trans('customers.general.table.business_name') }}</th>
                    <th class="">{{ trans('customers.general.table.document') }}</th>
                    <th class="">{{ trans('customers.general.table.phone') }}</th>
                    <th class="">{{ trans('customers.general.buttons.email') }}</th>
                    <th>{{ trans('labels.general.actions') }}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div><!--table-responsive-->
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div><!--box-->
@endsection

@section('after-scripts-end')
{{ Html::script("js/backend/plugin/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js") }}
{{ Html::script("js/backend/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js") }}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#customers-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route("admin.customers.get") }}',
                type: 'get',
                data: {active: 1}
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'check', name: 'check', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'rnc', name: 'rnc'},
                {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ],
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 0,
                'searchable':false,
                'orderable':false,
                'className': 'dt-body-center',
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
                }
            }],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [10, 20, 30, 60, -1],
                [10, 20, 30, 60, "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.all') }}"]
            ],
            language: {
                "sProcessing": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.processing') }}",
                "sSearchPlaceholder": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.search_placeholder') }}",
                "search": "",
                "lengthMenu": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.show') }} _MENU_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.records_by_page') }}",
                "zeroRecords": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.no_results') }}",
                "info": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.showing_page') }} _PAGE_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.of') }} _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.empty') }}",
                "infoFiltered": "({{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.filtered_of') }} _MAX_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.total_records') }})",
                "sInfo": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.showing_from') }} _START_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.to') }} _END_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.of') }} _TOTAL_ {{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.records') }}",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.previous') }}",
                    "next": "{{ trans('strings.backend.general.table.next') }}"
                }
            },
            order: [[0, "asc"]],
            searchDelay: 500
        });
        // Handle click on "Select all" control
        $('#example-select-all').on('click', function(){
            // Get all rows with search applied
            var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
            // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        // Handle click on checkbox to set state of "Select all" control
        $('#example tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
            // If checkbox is not checked
            if(!this.checked){
                var el = $('#example-select-all').get(0);
                // If "Select all" control is checked and has 'indeterminate' property
                if(el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)){
                    // Set visual state of "Select all" control
                    // as 'indeterminate'
                    el.indeterminate = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Handle form submission event
        $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
            var form = this;

            // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
            table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
                if(!$.contains(document, this)){
                    // If checkbox is checked
                    if(this.checked){
                        // Create a hidden element
                        $(form).append(
                                $('<input>')
                                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                                        .attr('name', this.name)
                                        .val(this.value)
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@stop
```

in my view im retreiving all the results but its also showing the ones that i have disabled with value 1, i just want to show the ones with value 0 in the list, any help would be really appreciated.

thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scopes or global scopes in your model, so those records are not retrieved at all.
In your model:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->where('parameter', 1);
    }
```

This will return only the records where the parameter = 1.